# show a group of thumbnails in windows phone 7 app

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, thumbnails

I wanted to ask what is the best way to show a group of thumbnails in wp7 app? Should I use stacks or lists or should i bind them to the content panel grid directly. I wanted to show 2 columns of thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you, you should use the

```
Wrappanel
```

embedded in listbox's itemtemplate.

Which gives the View like Picture hub in WP7.

For more [information on how to create  use this link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Image_listing_in_Qt_and_WP7)
Check for Wp7 Image listing.

or [use this link to how to create the same](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth)